# Digest authentication on http requests from clojure (?)

Tags: clojure, digest-authentication

I would like to consume a REST API using **clojure**, but I need to use **digest authentication.** I've been googling, but I can find no direct support for it in any of the client libs, and the documentation on the Java side (as well as on digest auth implementations in general) is poor.

I would basically like to get *recommendations on the easiest route* to get digest authentication working on my http requests from clojure.

Answer (score 3):

[clj-http](https://github.com/getwoven/clj-http) uses HttpComponents that have digest authentication (see [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)). Maybe you can cook something with that.